# My stylesheet works only when in mobile view, it worked fine yesterday but today all styles are gone if viewed on desktop

Tags: php, html, css, stylesheet

So I wrote a small website and everything was working great, all styles were working but today it only displays the style sheet in mobile view in the normal desktop view it disregards all the styles in my css/style.css

The navbar and header imag keeps their style regardless of the size of the browser just the rest of the styles are gone when in desktop view

My header and footer is included in all pages with php includes the files is in includes/header.php and includes/footer.php

Here is the link to the project as well  to look at maxi.maxihome.co.za

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">



   <!-- Bootstrap--!>
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

```
 <!-- Style sheet -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

 <!--Google Fonts  -->
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css? 
 family=Acme|Neuton&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"><link 
 href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css? 
 family=Acme|Neuton|PT+Mono&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"><link 
 href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css? 
 family=Acme|Neuton|PT+Mono|Sintony&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css? 
family=Acme|Molengo|Neuton|PT+Mono|Sintony&display=swap" 
 rel="stylesheet">


 <!-- js script header -->
<script type="text/javascript"src="js/app.js">

</script>

<title>Maxi Home Renovations</title>
</head>
<body>
<section class="header">


  <!-- custom menu -->
  <div class="nav">
      <div class="logo">
   <img class="imagelogo"src="images/name.png" alt="">
      </div>


      <div class="togg">
          <div></div>
          <div></div>
          <div></div>
      </div>
   <ul class="firstlevel">
   <li><a href=""></a></li>
   <li><a href=""></a></li>
   <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="services.php">Services</a></li>
   <li class="has-sub"><a>Renovations</a>
              <ul class="sub">
                      <li><a href="kitchen.php">Kitchen</a></li>
                      <li><a href="bathroom.php">Bathroom</a></li>
                      <li><a href="living.php">Living Area</a></li>
                      <li><a href="total.php">Total Renovation</a></li>
                  </ul></li>
          <li><a href="contact.php">Contact Us</a></li>
          <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-facebook-square"></i></a></li>


        </ul>

    </div>



  <img class="headerImage" src="images/headerImg.png" 
  alt="HeaderImage">

</section>

</body>
```

```
/*index page*/


<?php
include "includes/header.php" ?>

<section class="feature">

<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div id="carouselExampleInterval" class="carousel slide" data- 
       ride="carousel">
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active" data-interval="5000">
          <img class="imgCar"src="images/h1.JPG" class="d-block w-100" 
             alt="...">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item" data-interval="5000">
          <img class="imgCar"src="images/h2.JPG" class="d-block w-100" 
         alt="...">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item" data-interval="5000">
          <img class="imgCar" src="images/h3.jpg" class="d-block w-100" 
           alt="...">
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleInterval" 
             role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"> 
        </span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleInterval" 
          role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"> 
          </span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>

  </div>
  <?php
include "includes/footer.php" ?>

.headerImage{
 width: 100%;
 heigth: 300px;
 padding-top:75px;
 color:#bf2132;
 }

 .fimage{
  width: 100%;
  heigth: 300px;
  padding-top:75px;

  }

  .navbar-default{
  background-color:#bf2132;
   border-color: #bf2132;
    }




       /* navigation */

  .nav
   {
   width:100%;
   background-color:#ccc;
   position:fixed;
   top:0;
   left:0;
   z-index: 9999;
   }

  .nav .logo
  {
   display:flex;
   width:200px;
   height: 50px;
   flex-wrap:wrap;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   text-transform:uppercase;
   cursor:pointer;
   }
   .imagelogo{
   width:100px;
   heigth:50px;
   }
  .togg
   {
   position:absolute;
   right:40px;
   top:20px;
   display:none;
   z-index: 5;
   }
  .togg div {
   width: 36px;
   height: 2px;
   background-color: red;
   margin: 6px 0px;
   position: relative;
   transition:all .8s ease;
   }
  .togg.lijo div
     {
      position:absolute;
       transition:all .8s ease;
       }
     .togg.lijo div:nth-child(1){
     transform: rotate(48deg);
       top: 7px;
     /* position: absolute; */
     right: 0px;
        }
     .togg.lijo div:nth-child(2)
        {

       width:0px;
       top: 7px;
      /* position: absolute; */
       right: 0px;
       }
       .togg.lijo div:nth-child(3)
      {
       transform: rotate(-48deg);
       top: 7px;
       right: 0px;
       }
     .nav ul.firstlevel
      {
      list-style:none;
      width:calc(100% - 200px);
      background: rgb(191,33,50);
      background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(191,33,50,1) 0%, 
      rgba(247,77,5,0.9976365546218487) 33%, rgba(191,33,50,1) 100%);
      margin-bottom:0px;
      padding-left:0px;
      }
      .nav ul.firstlevel li
       {
        display:inline-block;
        margin-bottom:0px;
        color:#000;

         }

      .nav ul.firstlevel li a
        {
        cursor:pointer;
         display:block;
        padding:15px;
        transition:.8s ease;
        text-decoration:none;
        text-transform:uppercase;
        color:#fff;
       }
    .nav ul.firstlevel li a:hover
     {
      text-decoration:none;
      }
    .nav ul.firstlevel li ul.sub li {
       display: block;
        background-color:rgba(191,33,50,1);
       }
    .nav ul.firstlevel li ul.sub li:hover {
     display: block;
     background-color:rgba(172, 78, 2, 0.79);
      }
   .nav ul.firstlevel li ul.sub li a{
    color:#fff;
      }
    .nav ul.firstlevel li ul.sub
       {
     width:200px;
     position:absolute;
     padding-left:0px;
     opacity:0;
     visibility: hidden;
    transform:translateY(30px);
    transition:.5s linear;
    padding-top:20px;
   }
  .nav ul.firstlevel li ul.sub:after {
   content: '';
   width: 41px;
   height: 20px;
   border-bottom: solid 18px rgba(191,33,50,1);
   border-left: solid 20px transparent;
   border-right: solid 21px transparent;
   top: 0px;
   display: block;
   position: absolute;
   left: 16px;
    }
  @media(min-width:1024px)
   {
    .nav ul.firstlevel li:hover ul.sub
   {
    visibility:visible;
    opacity:1;
    transform:translateY(0px);
  }
  .nav ul.firstlevel li:hover
 {
   display:inline-block;
   margin-bottom:0px;
   background-color: rgba(27, 27, 27, 0.32);;
   color:#fff !important;
  }
  .nav ul.firstlevel li:hover a
  {
   color:#fff !important;
   }
   }


  @media(max-width:1024px)
  {
   .nav
   {
       min-height:50px;
   }
  .togg
  {
   display:block;
   top:10px;
  }
  .nav ul.firstlevel
   {
    position: absolute;
   top: 50px;
   transform: translateX(100%);
    right: 0;
    transition:.8s ease;
    width:40%;
    height: calc(100vh - 50px);
    z-index: fixed;
  }
  .nav ul.firstlevel li {
   display: block;
   }
 .nav ul.firstlevel.surya {
  transform: translateX(0%);
  }
 .nav ul.firstlevel li ul.sub
 {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  display:none;
  position:relative;
  padding-top:0px;
  width:100%;
  transition:0s;
  transform: translateY(0px);
  }
.nav ul.firstlevel li ul.sub:after
 {
 display:none;
 }


 /* Feature */

 .feature{
 padding-left: 100px;
 padding-right: 100px;
 padding-top: 70px;
 padding-bottom: 70px;
 background-image: url("../images/paper.jpg");
 text-align:center;
 }
.houseimg{
 width: 400px;
 height: 350px;
 border:5px solid rgb(191,33,50);
background-color:#ff0;

 }
.about{
 padding-right: 100px;
 padding-left: 100px;
 padding-bottom: 70px;
 text-align:center;
 background-image: url("../images/paper.jpg");
 }

 /* spinning text */
 #blink{
    width:100%;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
}
.htext{

    font-family: "Alfa Slab One";
    color: rgb(191,33,50);
    animation: blink 1.5s linear infinite;
     padding-bottom: 100px;
}
     @keyframes blink{
     0%{opacity: 0;}
    50%{opacity: .5;}
   100%{opacity: 1;}
   }

   /* paragraph background */
  .backpar{
   border-radius: 25px;
   background: rgb(191,33,50);
   background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(191,33,50,1) 0%, 
   rgba(247,77,5,0.9976365546218487) 33%, rgba(191,33,50,1) 100%);
  padding: 20px;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
  color: white;
  font-family: "Concert One";
   }
 .footer{
   background-image: url("../images/footer.png");
    }
    /* Contact */
      .contact{
      padding-left: 70px;
       padding-right: 70px;
       padding-top: 70px;
       padding-bottom: 70px;
       background-image:url("../images/paper.jpg");
      }
     .jumbotron {
        background: rgb(191,33,50);
         color: #FFF;
        border-radius: 0px;

           }
        .jumbotron-sm { padding-top: 24px;
        padding-bottom: 24px; }
       .jumbotron small {
       color: #FFF;
       }
     .h1 small {
     font-size: 24px;
     }

     /*  carousel homepage*/
     .carousel-item{
    width: 100% !important;
     Height: 350px !important;}

   .imgCar{
   width: 100% !important;
   Height: 350px !important;
   border: 2px solid red;
   border-radius: 5px;
   }
```

Comment: the link `maxi.maxihome.co.za` - the HTML is invalid - it is NOT a proper HTML document... sort that and you'll probably find all is well again

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed I left out a curly bracket everything is working again
*Embarrassed* Thank you

Comment: The HTML is still not being properly rendered - there is content AFTER the closing `</html>` tag